# Symfony - How to solve the doctrine issue of the missing annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I need a little help hand.

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Index;


/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="system_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
...
}
```

The Doctrine see problem with that annotation. I checked out all available issues what I can find, but none of resolve can't resolve my.

Error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table" in class UserBundle\Entity\User does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

autoload.php:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Composer:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "license": "Commercial",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "...",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.5",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "2.0.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.1",
        "nelmio/security-bundle": "^1.8",
        "willdurand/faker-bundle": "^1.3",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.3",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.0",
        "acseo/change-password-bundle": "dev-master#9c42fab1aa67e0b2211e37832bf3a2a398cb9b42",
        "snc/redis-bundle": "^1.1",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.5",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^4.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
        "ftrrtf/rollbar-bundle": "^0.15.1",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
        "iio/libmergepdf": "~3.0",
        "php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle": "^1.10",
        "darsyn/ip": "3.3.*",
        "thadafinser/user-agent-parser": "2.0.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^1.11",
        "browscap/browscap-php": "^3.0",
        "donatj/phpuseragentparser": "^0.5.0",
        "endorphin-studio/browser-detector": "^3.0",
        "handsetdetection/php-apikit": "^4.1.10",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.3",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.7.5",
        "piwik/device-detector": "^3.6",
        "sinergi/browser-detector": "^6.0",
        "ua-parser/uap-php": "^3.4.3",
        "whichbrowser/parser": "^2.0.10",
        "woothee/woothee": "^1.2",
        "mimmi20/wurfl": "^1.7.1.1",
        "zsxsoft/php-useragent": ">=1.2,<1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
        "phing/phing": "^2.14",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.3.*",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.6",
        "phploc/phploc": "^3.0",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.4",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I will be glad if someone will resolve this issue. I can`t.

Comment: try to add 
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }

in your app/config/config.yml

Comment: How does your composer.json look?

Comment: @Sylvain I have already set the validation in framework.

Comment: @paxi ok so can you show us your composer.json ?

Comment: @Sylvain I add composer,json in first post.

Comment: @paxi do you still have the problem if you add in your entity : use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table; ?

Comment: and put @ORM\Entity before the @ORM\Table (without the repositoryclass)

Comment: @Sylvain I tried and unfortunately this nothing change

Comment: @paxi you also have some problem in your autoloader. Not a lot of chance the problem come from here, but try to change that so we can be sure : `/** @var ClassLoader $loader */` =>
 `/** (next line)
* @var ClassLoader $loader(next line)
*/`

Comment: @paxi ok so you don't have the SymfonyStandard in your composer.json try to add after classmap : `"SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/"`

Comment: @Sylvain Still nothing...

Comment: what's your error message if you delete @ORM\Table ?

Comment: The error message is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try clearing and warming the cache for the environment you are running this in?

```sh
php app/console cache:clear -e test
php app/console cache:warmup -e test
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was epic. I copied app_dev.php from master (in that time, but now is v. 3.4) where annotation has not autoload from '../app//autoload.php'. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see no one can solve this, so I paste my contenf from config.yml:

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions'
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
            ip: Darsyn\IP\Doctrine\IpType
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        class_metadata_factory_name:  Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory
        default_repository_class:  Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        auto_mapping: true
        resolve_target_entities:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\User: UserBundle\Entity\User
```