# Symfony Doctrine Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm tried to create a new Symfony project with the standard procedure "symfony new my_project_name --full". If I try to access a defined route "/test" I'm getting the following Exception:

REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class App\Entity\Provider does not exist" at C:\xampp\htdocs\Sauber\template\vendor\doctrine\persistence\lib\Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver.php line 179

The Class App\Entity\Provider is an entity from another project and isn't defined anywhere in the new project and I just don't unserstand where this is coming from.

Comment: sounds like a localhost / local server setup issue...

Comment: do you use the build in dev server "server:start" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it warming the cache for the environment as in this link:
[Symfony - How to solve the doctrine issue of the missing annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794498/symfony-how-to-solve-the-doctrine-issue-of-the-missing-annotations).

Basically:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console cache:warmup
```

Answer (score 0):

As carlam.14 mentioned, running cache:clear may solve it for you. For me running it through the symfony CLI tool was what finally fixed this for me:

```
symfony console cache:clear
symfony console cache:warmup
```