# Symfony | Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class "App\Entity\Site" does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, exception

i have a git symfony project i want to work localy , after clone and composer install, i have this error : `Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class "App\Entity\Site" does not exist"` but this class is from an other project.

As mentioned in other topics as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023138/symfony-doctrine-uncaught-php-exception-reflectionexception) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794498/symfony-how-to-solve-the-doctrine-issue-of-the-missing-annotations), i cleared cache with `php bin/console cache:clear` `php bin/console cache:warmup` `symfony console cache:clear` ...
I tried to access to the website with `symfony server:start` and from xampp, same result.

I also tried to launch php server with `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/`.

Same result, it looks like it remains some caches somewhere i dont know ?

Comment: It's about entities, so it may be some doctrine cache already present. You can clear too, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826444/symfony-clear-doctrine-cache)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i cleared, but same result

Comment: Sometimes with windows there can be a case issue.  Verify you have a `src/Entity/Site.php` file and that it has a `namespace App\Entity;` line as well as a `class Site` line in it.  Any case mismatch can cause a problem with autoloading.  And just for kicks, you might also try `composer dump-autoload`.